# Redux store shape using spread

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Currently my state is overriding itself. 
I'm trying to do it so it doesn't override the data array. 
I need to access a specific index on data. The object inside of data array get's added based on component steps. But when UPDATE happens I need to do my spreads on a specific index of the data array without mutating it. How can I do this with what I got. I know I'm close.

```
const initialState = {
      index: 0,
      data: [{}],
    }; 



const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case UPDATE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [{
            ...state.data[state.count],
            [action.name]: { value: action.value },
          }],
      };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding `state.data` anytime UPDATE happens. What you're looking for is something like this:

```
const initialState = {
    index: 0,
    data: [{}],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                data: state.data.map((value, index) => {
                    if (index === state.count) {
                        return {
                            ...state.data[state.count],
                            [action.name]: { value: action.value },
                        }
                    }
                    return value;
                })
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that will keey adding to the array on every update which is called on every keystroke. I just want it to only update the data inside which every index you are on. I'll have another action type to handle updating the index value.

Comment: Something like data[state.index] ...update inside that

Comment: Oh, so you want to update an object at a specific index in the `state.data` array? If yes, I will update my answer :)

Comment: Yes thats what I'm after.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you have the index of interest `state.count`?

Comment: Yes state.count will get update in another action. UPDATE gets called as a user types which updates the object value. So on another action the count gets updated along with a new object is added. I should call it index makes more sense. But you get the idea.